# Attaching additional information to Yesod routes

Tags: routes, yesod

For my site I want to attach additional information to Yesod's routes. E.g. I'd like to have special navigation paths (previous page, next page, parent page etc.) or automatically create an overview page, use it for (hierarchical) breadcrumbs etc.

Basically, I'd like to be able to attach a record of my choice to a route. In the example this record could look like:

```
data AdditionalRouteInfo = ARI { nextPage :: Maybe (Route App)
                               , prevPage :: Maybe (Route App)
                               , parentPage :: Maybe (Route App)
                               , seeAlso :: [Route App]
                               , description :: String
                               }
```

Yesod's route attributes can only be strings, so this is not sufficient. My first impulse was to use `Data.Map (Route App) AdditionalRouteInfo` but then I discovered that `Route App` is not an instance of `Ord` :-(

So what is the recommended way to achieve this? The only way I can think of is writing a function `myRouteInfo :: Route App -> AdditionalRouteInfo` and pattern-match my way out of this dilemma. But this feels clumsy. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching is exactly what I would have recommended, since it means the compiler can check that you've addressed all cases. Yesod's built in breadcrumbs support follows this approach.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented it as suggested. Although I'd rather ``Route App`` was an instance of ``Ord`` :-)

Comment: You can always use StandaloneDeriving to get that instance yourself.